# Field Extension by a product of two elements

Tags: galois-theory

Let $L=K(a,b)$ and suppose there are natural numbers $m,n$ such that $(m,n)=1$. Assume that $a^m\in K$ and $b^n\in K$. How to prove that in this case $K(a,b)=K(ab)$?

I am unable to use Bezout's identity in a clever way to get anything useful.

Somethings that one can conclude from the hypothesis:

1)$Min(a,K)$ divides $m$
2)$min(b,K)$ divides $n$
3)$a=k_1a^{nt}$, $b=k_2b^{ms}$, where $k_1,k_2\in K$.

All one needs is to prove that $a\in K(ab)$ and similarly for $b$.

But this observations still dont give me anything useful to finish the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $sm + tn = 1$; that is, $sm = 1-tn$.

We have $a^mb^m = (ab)^m \in K(ab)$, so $b^m \in K(ab)$ and thus $b\cdot(b^n)^{-t}=(b^m)^s \in K(ab)$.  Therefore, $b \in K(ab)$ (and so $a\in K(ab)$ as well).

It follows that $K(a,b) = K(ab)$.